# Accessing Nested Elements with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, xsd, nokogiri

I'm trying to access elements within a elements in an XML doc. I think the fact I'm just beginning to learn about namespaces is tripping me up.

XSD Header

```
xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:gtig:/my/namespace" xmlns:XX="urn:gtig:/my/namespace" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

Because the original document does no comply to the schema, I need to loop through elements and update them. But I can't seem to access all elements within the xml structure. Here is a loop like mine:

This works just fine:

```
animals = @builder.doc.xpath("//myns:animal", 'myns' = 'urn:gtig:/my/namespace')
animals.each { |a|
  a.attributes['type'].remove
  a['newtype'] = "mammal"
```

But not this next part of the loop:

```
 c = a.xpath('cat/siamese')
```

Nor this:

```
c = a.xpath("//myns:cat/siamese", 'myns' = 'urn:gtig:/my/namespace')
```

"c" is empty. So, I'm able to access the animals, but not the elements within them.

XML Doc

```
<message xmlns="urn:gtig:/my/namespace" xmlns:XX="urn:gtig:/my/namespace" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <animal type="mammal">
    <cat>
      <siamese>value</siamese>
    </cat>
  </animal>
</message>
```

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". Your XML is invalid: `doc.errors # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: error parsing attribute name>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: attributes construct error>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Couldn't find end of Start Tag message line 1>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document>]` You're going to need to fix it if it's been mistyped, to accurately reflect what it should be, or, if it's wrong in the source you'll need to do a fixup prior to trying to parse it.

Comment: Thanks, I believe it is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out part my problem, which is I need to treat each animal as an XML Fragment.  So, I need to do this:

```
c = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(a)
siamese_cat = c.xpath(.//cat/siamese)
```

The problem now is I need to remove an attribute, and add a new one, on siamese_cat, which is a nodeset in my real life example. Haven't figured out the syntax on that yet.

Hopefully that will help someone else.

Comment: You rarely need to use DocumentFragment with a XML document. We iterate over sections using `search` or its CSS or XPath versions after parsing the entire document using `Nokogiri::HTML(...)` or `Nokogiri::XML(...)`. It sounds like you're going down the wrong path but your example data isn't sufficient to help you. There are numerous examples here on SO that demonstrate the process.

Comment: Thanks Tin Man. When I get back into that task, I'll go back and start over that piece without DocumentFragment.